# Use LATEX’s picture environment to make a picture of a 3–4–5 Pythagorean triangle,

Tags: picture-mode

i have written the coe but the hypotenies is not coming out right
here is my code

```
\begin{picture}(450,350)
\put(0,0){\circle{5}}
\put(450,350){\circle{5}}
\put(450,0){\circle{5}}
\put(0,350){\circle{5}}
\put(400,25){\line(0,1){300}}
\put(0,25){\line(1,0){400}}
\put(400,325){\line(-1,-1){500}}
\end{picture}
```

the packages used in the overall code  are inputenc, amsmath,  gensymband graphicx

[image: this is the output]

the four circles are there just for my reference

what am i doing wrong?
right now i have an okay grasps of assigning coordinate ,any tips or advice  is still appreciated

also assigning the vector still confuses me and i have opt for trial and error which i hate to do so any help with that plss

thanks

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Picture seems to be a decent reference.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For `\line` the () argument gives the tangent, and the length is the horizontal length except for vertical lines

```
\documentclass{article}
\addtolength\textwidth{2in}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{picture}(450,350)
\put(0,0){\circle{5}}
\put(450,350){\circle{5}}
\put(450,0){\circle{5}}
\put(0,350){\circle{5}}
\put(400,25){\line(0,1){300}}
\put(0,25){\line(1,0){400}}
\put(0,25){\line(4,3){400}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: they are to be 5-4-3 but according to your code it will be of ratio 4-4-3

Comment: also what is the reason behind using (4,3) as line vector for the hypotheues?

Comment: @Priyanka_3030 that line is 4 along and 3 up, with horizontal length 400.  As I say (4,3 )is essentially specifying the tangent is 3/4

Comment: @Priyanka_3030 No this is a 3-4-5 triangle, not 3-4-4

Comment: okay got the vector part but sir the does seem to be of 5-4-3 but the lenght assigned to them is 300,400 and 400..?  shouldn't  it be 300,400 and500 . when i put these value the result is not desired so is it a tech issue??

Comment: as I have said above multiple times: the length is the horizontal length not the length of the line @Priyanka_3030

Comment: oh..okay thank you

Comment: excuse me can you help me with another trouble i am facing..? i am trying to incribe this triangle in a circle  under picture environment only but i am unable to get a circle with diameter greater than 40...

Comment: @Priyanka_3030 see  `pict2e` package (but please don't ask new questions in comments)

Comment: thanks.. i won't :)